# Terminal not clearing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to clear the terminal but the terminal isn't clearing, instead a character of some sort is inserted into the terminal. What other methods can i use to clear the terminal?

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Pycharm latest version

```
import os

while True:
    date = input("\nEnter the date (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    direction = input("\nEnter trade direction (buy, sell): ")
    lotsize = float(input("\nEnter lotsize: "))
    entry = float(input("\nEnter entry price: "))
    profit = float(input("\nEnter take profit price: "))
    loss = float(input("\nEnter stop loss price: "))
    outcome = input("\nEnter the result (loss/win): ")

    with open(file="data.csv", mode="a") as file:
        data = f"\n{date}, {direction}, {outcome}, {lotsize}, {entry}, {profit}, {loss}"
        file.write(data)
        os.system("cls")
```

[image: The terminal is not cleared]

Comment: What OS are you using? On linux you need to use "clear"

Comment: I am using windows, along with pycharm ide.

Comment: @Chemik , yes it does answer my question, thank you.